# What should I type in python to open a file located on my desktop when using a Mac?

Tags: python, macos

When I opened a `.txt` file located in a folder called scripts on my h-drive using Windows I typed this:

```
F = open('h:\\scripts\\data.txt')
```

I copied the file to a USB drive (n:) and now I want to access this file by using Python on a macbook. I typed this:

```
P = open('n:\\data.txt')
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.txt'
```

So I guess I need to use a different way of specifying pathways to folders when using Python on a Macbook?

Thank you for the replies, sorry for asking the original question without explaining it properly, but as you can tell I am completely new to coding.

Comment: You really should post the code.

Comment: It's not a Python's fault. The file n:\\data.txt doesn't exist for real on a Mac. It is a difference between operating systems that causes your problem. You asked for a file on Desktop, so my answer will open you a file if you copy it to Desktop. For instance open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/data.txt")) will do it. To open a file on the USB drive, you should look for it on /Volumes directory. For example /Volumes/KINGSTON/data.txt.

Comment: Learn something about differences between Unix based OSes and Windows/Dos and then start to program. If you do not, you will constantly run in such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by open you mean that you want to get a file() object back, then:

```
import os
filename = "Your_file.something"
username = os.environ["USER"]
f = open(os.path.join("/Users", username, "Desktop", filename), <mode>)
```

But there should be a $HOME variable present which will give you the real home folder even if it is not named as the user:

```
f = open(os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], "Desktop/Your_file.something"), <mode>)
```

That is if shell alias for home folder won't work:

```
f = open("~/Desktop/Your_file.something", <mode>)
```

BTW, <mode> is of course the mode you wish to open your file in ("r", "w", "rb", "wb", "a", "ab", etc.)

Comment: `open("~/...")` definitely will NOT work.  Also note that you can use `os.path.expanduser()`.

Comment: Yes, it will not, as it is mostly logical. I wasn't at Mac at the moment I wrote the A so I was unable to check if it works or not. And yes, os.path.expanduser("~") will give us back the absolute path to home folder. I forgot about this naughty little function. Thanks for adding it. I'd just like that OP rewords his Q, making clear what he really wants.